# Drivers for TP-LINK TL-WN723N v3

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless, driver, pi-2

I need the drivers for my wireless adapter (TP-LINK TL-WN723N v3). I googled a lot, but could not find latest drivers. All I could find were the drivers for TP-LINK TL-WN725N.
My raspbian version is 3.18.7-v7+ #755.
Will these drivers work for me?

Otherwise, is there any way that I can compile the drivers myself?

Comment: Have you tried plugging it in?   If there's a driver for it you should see `wlan0` listed with `ip link`.   If that doesn't work try `sudo modprobe 8192cu` and `ip link` again, but I don't think there's a driver for this one.

Comment: I tried both but it lists only `lo` and `eth0`. I tried installing the drivers or TL-WN725N, but still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TP-LINK TL-WN723N v3 uses the same chipset as TP-LINK TL-WN723N v2.
So, I solved the problem by installing the drivers for the same.

These links were helpful.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=422209
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=62371

I also had to reinstall the `firmware-realtek` package.

Comment: `wget http://www.fars-robotics.net/8188eu-4.4.8-v7-881.tar.gz`
`tar xzf 8188eu-4.4.8-v7-881.tar.gz`
`./install.sh`

ref: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982#p462982

Comment: `sudo wget http://www.fars-robotics.net/install-wifi -O /usr/bin/install-wifi`
`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/install-wifi`
`sudo install-wifi -h`

ref: http://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982#p462982

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is a bit late, but for all the others who are still looking:

To have the TP-Link TL-WN725N v2 and v3 working use the following commands in the terminal

First type:

```sh
$ sudo su -
```

Then type

```sh
$ wget http://raspishop.pl/downloads/8188eu.ko-raspbian -O /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko
```

And after that

```sh
$ depmod -a
```

Next type the following command

```sh
$ sed -i 's/^exit 0/modprobe 8188eu\nexit 0/' /etc/rc.local
```

Finally, reboot using

```sh
$ reboot
```

This worked perfectly for me. I have a way better wi-fi connection now

Comment: You should put the module that needs to be loaded at boot time in `/etc/modules` and the kernel will modprobe it automatically. No need for any changes to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Why would you use `sudo su`?

Comment: @RalfFriedl because it looks cleaner. using <code>sudo su - </code>will automatically put you in as a root user. You don't have to type sudo before every command

Comment: I prefer to use `sudo -Es` instead of `sudo su -` because then you have a known environment. Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that you need to by a compatible wifi device as drivers are not always available for the device you have.  I use usb wifi adapters that contain Realtek chipsets: rtl8176 and rtl 8188CE.  I purchased my wifi adapters from Adafruit, Amazon and Fry's Electronic.  Be sure to check the chipset before you buy!  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a completely automatic download/install (Raspberry Pi2 only) program check [here](http://carlocervellin.blogspot.it/2016/03/completely-automatic-tp-link-tl-wn725n.html). This installer is for TL-WN725N, but,
 mentioned, it should work the same. It makes also simpler to install the driver after updating the operating system, and allows you to install even without requiring a connection different from the one provided by the wifi adapter!

Comment: Your link goes to an installer for the TL-WN725N, rather than the TL-WN723N. Can you confirm that that driver is compatible?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: you say `as someone mentioned`... who mentioned this? Can you cite a source for that confirmation?

Comment: The top comment has mentioned it, and it has been accepted as best answer, so it's assumable that it worked. The second link redirects to the TL-WN725N drivers list